# How to put Marquee text in Wordpress in childcare_breadcrumbs.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, text, breadcrumbs, marquee

I wants to put Marquee text in every page just below header menus in Wordpress.
So how i put will put?

```
if( !function_exists('childcare_breadcrumbs') ):
    function childcare_breadcrumbs() {
        global $post;
        $homeLink = home_url();
    ?>
    <div class="page-header-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class=" col-md-12 page-header-inner data-anim-type="">
            <?php
                echo '<ul id="mytabs">';
                echo '</ul>'    
            ?>  
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
```